# visual studio 2008 asp.net project templates missing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My desktop management team have just installed visual studio 2008 and there is no pluggins for asp.net ..

is this missed out while they installed visual studio?

can this to be installed again??

Comment: Which plugins would that be? Or do you by any chance mean project templates or IIS handlers?

Comment: yes project templates ..mistaken... i am editing the question !!

Answer (score 0):

Did they install the Web Development tools? It's an option in the installer.

If you go to Help | About you should see something like:

> Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

listed in the "Installed Products" list.

Running the installer a second time, and ensuring that option is checked should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the project templates folder first:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx

and see if the templates are there.  You can always try repairing the VS installation...